# Is there an edit distance metric which doesn't rely on order at all?

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

For example, let's say I have these two lists:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [3,2,1];
```

The Levenshtein distance between them would be 2. I'm looking for a metric where the distance would be 0, i.e. lists with the same elements are regarded as the same list, regardless of order. I've searched online, but I'm not really sure what terminology is used for this sort of thing.

Comment: How about sorting the lists before comparing?

Comment: @evan058 Can't think of a reason why not.

Comment: @evan058 Okay I thought of a reason: sorting + finding the edit distance is much more to process than calculating the Jaccard index, since that's just finding the intersection and then dividing its magnitude by the magnitude of the union of the two sets.

Comment: Well sorting can happen in `n*log(n)` time which I am sure is less than these distance algorithms, but after reading more about the Levenshtein distance it does seem to be overkill if you do not care about order. Jaccard it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a set distance like the [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

Comment: This is exactly it, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just sort the arrays and run regular edit distance?